# Is there a way to override the host header when making a verified SSL request in python-requests?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I'd like to override the host header in python requests.  Mainly so that I can retry with a different resolved ip on a failure.  But it seems like I'm not able to verify the hostname when overriding the host with a header.

```
import requests
import socket

host, alias, ip = socket.gethostbyname_ex("www.google.com")
requests.get("https://%s" % ip[0], headers={"Host": "www.google.com"})
```

requests.exceptions.SSLError: hostname '74.125.196.147' doesn't match 'www.google.com'

Comment: That' what load balancers are for. You're trying to deal with a problem you don't have.

Comment: @kedar: You are right, but overriding host header is useful in similar cases - when you have load balancer that you want to skip using same domain. Useful eg. for checking health of various hosts behind single load balancer.

Comment: Did you get to fix this? I'm running into a very similar problem with the difference that I'm not trying to verify the certificate. If I remove the Host header it works. Using the host header works through curl without problems.